# deleting file used for attachment built with Spring MimeMessagePreparator

Tags: java, spring, callback, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have code like this, that builds and sends an email with attachment:

```
public void sendMail(final Data data) {
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper emailMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            emailMessage.setTo("joe@yahoo.com");
            emailMessage.setFrom("joe@yahoo.com");
            emailMessage.setSubject("Hello");

            Map model = getVelocityModel(data);
            String emailBody = 
                    VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, velocityTemplate, "UTF-8",                          model);
            emailMessage.setText(emailBody, true);

            //send an attachment if appropriate

                File attachment = getAttachmentFile(model);
                emailMessage.addAttachment(attachmentName, attachment);
        }
    };

    try {
        this.mailSender.send(preparator);
    } catch (MailException e) {
        log.error("Error:" + e);
    }
}
```

getAttachmentFile creates a file and merges it with the velocity template to create the attachment.
I need to delete the attachment after the email is sent. I find this difficult to achieve, as it cannot be done in the callback, yet by the time mailSender.send is called, I don't have access to the File object any more to delete it.
I'd be grateful for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a final collection declared before the MimeMessagePreparator and add the file(s) to it (or the path(s) to each file). 
After the message it's send, delete the files.

```
        final List<File> attachments = Lists.newArrayList();

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper emailMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
                emailMessage.setTo("joe@yahoo.com");
                emailMessage.setFrom("joe@yahoo.com");
                emailMessage.setSubject("Hello");

                Map model = getVelocityModel(data);
                String emailBody =
                    VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, velocityTemplate, "UTF-8", model);
                emailMessage.setText(emailBody, true);

                //send an attachment if appropriate

                File attachment = getAttachmentFile(model);
                emailMessage.addAttachment(attachmentName, attachment);
                attachments.add(attachment);
            }
        };

        try {
            this.mailSender.send(preparator);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            log.error("Error:" + e);
        }

        //Call method to delete files
```